# Hyperledger composer REST API authentication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am creating an iphone app which will call hyperledger composer's rest API's. I have used GITHUB passport setup for authentication. When I go to http://locahost:3000/explorer from a browser it shows me an access token on top. Using this access token I am able to perform transactions from my APP. My question is how do I get this access token from app without having to go to a browser to retrieve access token?

Comment: I think there is a cookie set called "access_token" from which you can extract the token.  This blog and the samples contained with it may also help you https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc

Comment: I did find a code on another thread doing exactly what you are suggesting.  Using this code I am able to extract JWT access token from cookies. Thanks